# C# webbrowser control, change right click option

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i need your help to create a right click option in webbrowser control i have.
may be if i right click in a link will open this option :
open in new tab
open in new window
copy link
please help me create a the C# code and the explaination, because i am a newbie in webbrowser control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to create your own context menu using Visual studio.  Just drop a context menu item onto your form, and boom, your almost done.

Add the buttons you want, handle their click/changed events as necessary.

Then, in your code, either use the properties on the webBrowser control to change the context menu to the one you created, or handle it in code on Form_Load.

```
 private void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    mainBrowser.ContextMenuStrip = browserCMenu;
 }
```

Where browserCMenu would be created inside of the designer, but you could create from code as well:

```
this.browserCMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);

// This is the AddRange() command for items.  
// You basically create your controls first (buttons, checkboxes, etc), and then assign
// them here, so they are added to your control.
this.browserCMenu.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
    this.copylinkMenuItem,
    this.copyMenuitem}); 

this.browserCMenu.Name = "browserCMenu";
this.browserCMenu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 48);
```

Note that the above is designer generated code.  As you'll be (most likely) using the Visual Studio designer to do your work you can just do the following steps:

1. Drag a ContextMenuStrip item from the toolbox to your form.
2. Click on 'Type Here' to name your new button, or click the arrow to add different type of controls.
3. Then simply double click on the control you added (button, list, etc), to handle the click event/chagned event for the context menu item, and add your code.
4. Assign that context menu, as the context menu for the web browser by changing the web browser context menu item (as shown in the Form1Load() section above).

You can also query what type of text is being targeted as well, but i wont go into that here, you can search MSDN for that information, or search here on StackOverflow, there are several articles on that.  But that will allow you to obtain different context menus for different types of data being right clicked (i dont find it that useful personally).  It's best just to present a **standard** context menu for all browser controls, that use the same context menu items, so that your code isn't bogged down/too complex with too many context menus.